# AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'ranking_'

Tags: scikit-learn

I tried to get features ranking, by using followings:

```
1. Standardscaler
2. RandomForestClassifier
3. Recursive feature selection


from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data = load_iris()

X = data.data
Y = data.target

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

estimators = [('standardize' , StandardScaler()),
             ('rfecv', RFECV(estimator=clf, scoring='accuracy'))]

pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)

ranking_features = pipeline.named_steps['rfecv'].ranking_
print (ranking_features)
```

AttributeError: 'RFECV' object has no attribute 'ranking_'

Any best practice to do this is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first use `rfecev` to fit the data before calling the `ranking_` attribute. Try running this code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data = load_iris()

X = data.data
Y = data.target

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

estimators = [('standardize' , StandardScaler()),
             ('rfecv', RFECV(estimator=clf, scoring='accuracy'))]

# create pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)

# fit rfecv to data
rfecv_data = pipeline.named_steps['rfecv'].fit(X, Y)

# get the feature ranking
ranking_features = rfecv_data.ranking_
print (ranking_features)

'Output':
[2 3 1 1]
```

Comment: It depends on how the pipeline is setup and how the model is constructed. In this case, it standardizes over the entire dataset. Ideally, you'll want to standardize on the training set so that you don't leak information from the train set to the test set. We can easily split the dataset using `train_test_split`.

Comment: I can do this, but this will require a very different approach entirely as this is a different question. If I modify this answer as is, it will not correspond with the Question/Anser format of StackOverflow. What you asked here and what this code is solving is simply to find the important features of the dataset using the Recursive Feature Elimination method. Probably frame a new question, and link me, i'll be glad to help out. Cheers.

Comment: @brute Done. Cheers.